# show other field if other selected in menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to display another field to capture users input if they select other in the select menu. My code is as below however the id otherJobType is not unhiding when I select Other in the menu. Can anyone spot where I have gone wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<style type="text/css">
#otherJobType {
    display:none;
}
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function jobType(value){
        if (value == 'Other') {
            document.getElementById('otherJobType').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('otherJobType').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>

<select id="jobType" name="jobType" onchange="jobType(this.value);">
    <option value="option 1" selected>Option 1</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input name="otherJobType" id="otherJobType" type="text" size="50" value="Please specify job type" onblur="if (this.value=='') { this.value='Please specify job type' }" onclick="if (this.value=='Please specify job type') { this.value='' }" />
```

Comment: Works in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/9XzKm/)

Comment: In what browser do you experience this problem? Any error messages? The jsFiddle Musa posted works for me either.

Comment: Dam, that jsFiddle works for me to. I'm experiencing the issue in firefox 12 (the only browser I've checked it in so far) maybe it's clashing with something else then on my page.

Comment: I've noticed I get 'jobType is not a function' in the firefox error console

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in the end by renaming the function to "workJobType" but leaving the id and the name on the select menu as "jobType". If either of these were the same as the function name it didn't work for some reason. I would love to hear if someone could explain why it didn't work?

It's stange because everything worked fine in the jsfiddle that Musa posted but on my page which has lots more going on it wasn't working until I change the function name I was using.